# Not being able to create a push notifier in apigee

Tags: apigee

I am trying to create a push notifier for my app. I follow the instructions provided: upload a .p12, name the notifier, development, etc. and then click create notifier. However the button does nothing! Anyone else facing the same issue?

Comment: What name did you give the notifier? Can you give an output of what you see in the browser console?

Comment: I called it "notifyme": the console spits what kevin has mentioned below

Comment: Yep - in short, you have to name it "apple" or "google" or it won't work ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have the same problem creating notifier for ios too. It seem to be something wrong with the admin console's java script.

`Error (400)(illegal_argument): provider must be one of: [noop, apple, google] usergrid-libs.min.js:13
Object {error: "illegal_argument", timestamp: 1391045372081, duration: 0, exception: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException", error_description: "provider must be one of: [noop, apple, google]"…}
duration: 0
error: "illegal_argument"
error_description: "provider must be one of: [noop, apple, google]"
exception: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"
timestamp: 1391045372081
proto: Object`

To solve this problem, you can create the notifier in the "Legacy Portal".
The button on the upper right conner next to your name or try the below link and replace your organization and application name. http://apigee.com/appservices/archive/#your_username/your_app_name/configuration

Answer (score 1):

Using the new App Services, you need to name the notifier either `apple` or `google` depending on your platform.

Answer (score 0):

A fix for this issue has been deployed. Thank you for bringing it to our attention.

Rod 
Apigee